# Vue - Token logged in state validation

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am able to identify if the user is logged-in using vuex store. The problem is when I manually changed the `access_token` in the browser (saved in cookies), I'm still considered as logged-in since the value is not null. How do I verify that the browser `access_token` is a valid token? I want to redirect them to log-in if it's not a valid one.

I think I will also have trouble when users use an expired token.

**app.js**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
      next({
        name: 'login',
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
    if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
      next({
        name: 'dashboard',
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

**vuex**

```
 loggedIn(state) {
      return state.token !== null
    }
```

Comment: Add `state.token !== Undefined` to the login function and you should be good to go

Comment: ReferenceError: Undefined is not defined

Comment: Not `undefined` as an string, `undefined` as in the value is not defined. The `U` in `undefined` should be lower case.  `return state.token !== null && state.token !== undefined`

Comment: I'm still logged in even after using undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your access token is generated by your server. You will need to send an ajax request with your token as data to the server and the server should check if the token is valid or not and you simply return an `true` or `false` and check that via an if statement

Comment: Will check this out.